# Looping through subfolders to run command in many directories

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, cmd.exe

I am on a Windows machine. However, I installed Cygwin and updated my environmental variable path which allows me to run Linux commands through a Windows terminal.

I would like to perform the following command:

```
wc -l * > total
```

in many folders. My setup is this:

Parent Folder has 24 subfolders each named PKA1, PKA2, etc., up to PKA24

I want to go into each subfolder. But within each subfolder I need to go further. I need to go down three more levels (only one subfolder in each directory at this point), but the path looks like:

```
PKA1/timestep_size/v_0.001/500eV
```

Then in each subfolder at this depth, there are 4 folders:

```
O1
O3
Si3
Si5
```

I would like to go into each one and perform my command. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many nested folders are there, you could try

```
wc -l * > file
wc -l */* >> file
wc -l */*/* >> file
```

etc.

Comment: this did not work. I need the file to be put into each directory, not just one large file in the parent directory

Comment: this creates one file which is fine but it creates really long columns. Can it create new columns for each file that makes up the final file?

Comment: you can create a file for each directory and then use `paste file1 file2 file2 > final_file`

Comment: I have been using this a lot. I like actually that it puts them all in one file. Is there a way in the commands above, I can paste them horizontally into the final folder? As opposed to file 1 above file 2 etc.?

Answer (score 0):

Use a FOR loop.

From your parent folder, do:

```
FOR /R %G IN (*) DO wc -l %G >>total
```

This should do the command for every file in that directory.

The /R switch makes it run through every file and >> appends, instead of overwrites the output to your file.

More info:

http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Cygwin does not understand the Windows format file paths without conversion ...